# Checkbox in gridviewcolumn(header)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, checkbox

I am using a listview (gridview/gridviewcolumn)
where the first column
contains only checkboxes for each row. Instead of adding a select all button I want
to add a Checkbox into the header of the first column.

Selecting the checkbox in the header will select
all other checkboxes and vice versa.

How can I do that in xaml?

Update:
This is the important part of my xaml code. (simplified)

```
<ListView ItemSource="...">
<ListView.View>
<GridView>

<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

</GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What have you done until now to achieve your goal? Show some of your code/XAML

Comment: Updated my question with the current xaml code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have a checkbox on top of GridViewColumn you can do something like this

```
<GridViewColumn>

 <GridViewColumn.Header>
     <CheckBox/>
  </GridViewColumn.Header>

  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Now you can handle the check event and in the code you can iterate through your itemsSource and change values or if you are following MVVM you can bind property with checkbox so that whenever check is changed you will be notified through `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Once you find out through binding that check has changed, again you can change your itemssource accordingly