# How do I get Checkbox to Bind in telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, telerik-grid, tableheader

I was going to add to [Checkbox in gridviewcolumn(header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034577/checkbox-in-gridviewcolumnheader/6036153#6036153), but since I am actually asking another question I felt it warranted a new post.

I found I can also do what Haris Hasan shows with Telerik:

```
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsReadOnly="False">
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedInUI, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AreAllSelected}"/>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
 </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

However, the problem I am running into is that my AreAllSelected property is not changed when I click on the checkbox. I also tried

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AreAllSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is the property in the ViewModel:

```
public bool AreAllSelected
{
    get { return _areAllSelected; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _areAllSelected) return;
        _areAllSelected = value;
    }
}
```

I have another checkbox outside the grid, where the property does get set successfully when clicked. It looks like this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AreAllSelected}">Check/Uncheck All Items</CheckBox>
```

I can set a breakpoint on the setter and it is hit when I click the checkbox that is outside the grid, but not if I click the checkbox in the header.

Why isn't the one in the header working, and is it simple to fix?

Thank you!